# Is it possible to write a function work for int and long (float, byte .etc) in F#?

Tags: f#, int, long-integer

when use

```
let add a b = a + b
```

it works for int. and

```
let add2 a b:float = a + b
```

work for float.

Is it possible to write a function work for int and long (float, byte .etc) in F#?

i need a function whose "a" work for int and long like this:

```
let f a b = a >>> b 
let f (a:int64) b = a >>> b
```

is it possible in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to write a function that can work with multiple different numeric types, you need to use `inline` and "static member constraints". The problem is that normal .NET generics cannot capture constraints like "supports the + operator".

To make your sample `add` function generic, you can use `inline`:

```
let inline add x y = x + y
```

When you look at the inferred type, you'll see something like this:

```
val inline add :
  x: ^a -> y: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

This essentially says that the function can be called on any two arguments that support the `+` operator. Note that this only works because the function is `inline` and so the F# compiler does not have to rely on .NET to express the constraints. The same works for the `>>>` operator:

```
let inline f a b = a >>> b
```

The function can now be used with both `int64` and `int` arguments:

```
f 1024L 2
f 1024 2
```

I wrote an article about [writing generic numeric code in F#](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/) some time ago which you may find useful too.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a sample of what you mean (ideally minimal sample to demonstrate what you want to get)?

Comment: i read your article and get it now. thank you very much and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @Syeerzy No problem, I'm also not a native English speaker (and welcome to StackOverflow!) - If you needed more help with using this inside a type, feel free to ask or edit & extend your question.

Comment: If you want to keep an 'infix' style you can define a custom operator: `let inline (++) a b = a + b` now you can do: `let c = 3 ++ 4`